# Isolating the background of a video with objects of interest present in the initial frame using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to locate moving cars from a traffic cam. The video I'm working with starts off with the objects of interest in the initial frame. My question is how would I go about isolating the background without any of the vehicles, to serve as the frame of origin for subsequent motion detection.

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(video)

firstFrame = None

while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()  
    if not grabbed:
        break

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=2, fy=2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)

    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for c in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 500:
            continue
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
    cv2.imshow('frame delta', frameDelta)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ultimately, first frame will be absent of any vehicles, proceeded by the original frames of the video.

Thanks

Comment: The code has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Ok. Disregarding the code and focusing on the question itself, is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you described, you should look more into object detection and classification. Locating moving cars is not particularly a background subtraction problem. An example of using Haar Cascades can be found here: https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you still want to use background subtraction, then you can try the Mixture of Gaussian. Here is a survey paper: https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/338206/filename/RPCS_2008.pdf. Opencv sample here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html.